# SQL Standard Based Hive Authorisation of Hive.13 does not work while pointing JDBC Application to Spark Thrift Server

Tags: apache-spark-sql

It seems like while pointing JDBC/ODBC Driver to Spark SQLThrift Service, the Hive's security feature SQL based authorization is not working. It ignores the security settings passed through the command line. The arguments for command line is given below for reference.

The problem is user X can do select on table belonging to user Y, though permission for table is explicitly defined and its a data security risk.

I am using Hive .13.1 and Spark 1.3.1 and here is the list arguments passed to Spark SQL Thrift Server.

```
    ./start-thriftserver.sh --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10001 --hiveconf xxxxhostname.compute.amazonaws.com --hiveconf 
hive.security.authenticator.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.SessionStateUserAuthenticator --hiveconf 
hive.security.authorization.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.sqlstd.SQLStdHiveAuthorizerFactory --hiveconf 
hive.server2.enable.doAs=false --hiveconf 
hive.security.authorization.enabled=true --hiveconf 
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive?
createDatabaseIfNotExist=true --hiveconf 
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --hiveconf
 javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName=hive --hiveconf
 javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword=hive.
```

I will appreciate if anyone can suggest a workaround for this.